# Proving $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ using monotonic sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}$, $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $x_0 \in A$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ $\iff$ given any monotonic
>   sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ in $A$ with $x_n \rightarrow x_0$, we
>   have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$

Here's my attempt:

"$\implies$" 
Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. By definition of continuity, for all sequences $\{t_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ with $t_n \rightarrow x_0$, we have $f(t_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$.
In particular, this is true for all monotonic sequences $\{x_n\}$ in A. Hence, we're done.

"$\impliedby$" Suppose for all monotonic sequences $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ with $x_n \rightarrow x_0$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$.

This is where I'm stuck, because I don't know how to go from monotonic sequences to all sequences. Intuitively, if we define piecewise $x_n = 1/n$ if $n$ is even and $x_n=-1/n$ if $n$ is odd, then this is a non-monotonic sequence with two monotonic subsequences $y_k = \frac{1}{2k}$ and $z_k = \frac{1}{2k+1}$ that converge to $0$, and so, by assumption, $f(y_k) \rightarrow f(0)$ and $f(z_k) \rightarrow f(0)$ so we can write up an $\epsilon - N$ proof that shows $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(0)$.

But is it generally true that all convergent sequences can be broken down to convergent monotonic subsequences? How do I make this rigorous?

Thanks!

Edit: Definition of convergence

> $(a_n)$ is said to converge to $l \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \geq N \implies |a_n -l| < \epsilon$.

Comment: What definition of convergence are you using exactly?

Comment: Edited to include definition of convergence.

Comment: Ask simpler questions. Can $f(x_n)$ be unbounded from above? If it were, can you construct a monotonic sub-sequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\to+\infty$? Note that if you manage that would contradict the assumption. The question for bounded from below is similar. So, $f(x_n)$ should be bounded. Now, let $x_{n_k}$ be a subsequence such that $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to some $L$. Can you construct a monotonic sub-subsequence $x_{n_{k_i}}$ of it? If you do then $L=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Finish by proving that if all convergent subsequences of a bounded sequence converge to the same limit, then the sequence is convergent.